# Count number of paths root to node sum equal to a certain number

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have to write a function that will count the number of paths of a binary tree from root to node that have a sum equal to a certain number. I have written the code below in c++ but the thing is that it only shows 1 path even when there are more than one. Can you help me solve it? Thank you!

```
int hasPathSum(struct node* node, int sum)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (node == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    else {
        int subSum = sum - node->data;
        if (subSum == 0 && node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)
            count++;

        if (node->left)
            count = count || hasPathSum(node->left, subSum);
        if (node->right)
            count = count || hasPathSum(node->right, subSum);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I recommend using a debugger to step through the code, and drawing the tree as you step through the code.  You may want to draw the tree first, then annotate the tree as you step through the code.

Comment: What (minimal) tree are you using?

Comment: Done that but cant find the mistake

Comment: In what way is this “showing” any path at all?

Comment: what do you think is `||` doing?

Comment: Why are you using the or operator with the int count??

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you asked for, hope it helps

```
int hasPathSum(struct node* n, int sum, int certain_number)
{
     if(n != nullptr){
         sum += n->data;
         if(n->left == nullptr && n->right == nullptr && sum == certain_number)
             return 1;

         else return hasPathSum(n->left, sum, certain_number) + hasPathSum(n->right, sum, certain_number)
    }

     return 0;

}
```